# How can I convert date and time to timestamp by giving/considering timezone?

Tags: python, timezone, timestamp, utc

I am trying to convert date and time to timestamp of different timezone.

Consider I have a string `2015-07-24T19:23:49+0530`.
Here I can able to get year(2015), Month(07), Date(24), Hours(19), Minutes(23), Seconds(49).

and lastly timezone (530 means IST).

My questions are.

1. Is converting above date to timestamp depends on timezone?
2. If yes, how can I convert above date into UTC?

I tried :

```
>>> dt = datetime(2015,03,19,20,18,15)
>>> timestamp = (dt - datetime(1970, 1, 1)).total_seconds()
>>> timestamp
1426796295.0
```

In above code it is considering local timezone.
Where can I pass timezone to get correct UTC time?

**I am not trying to convert local time to UTC timestamp.** 
In fact, string may contain other timezone as well.
Ex:

```
2015-07-24T19:23:49+0530 #-> This is for Indian timezone.
2015-07-24T19:23:49+0300 #-> This is Istanbul timezone.
```

But UTC timestamp will be different for both timezone.

My question is : How can I get UTC timestamp by considering timezone.

Comment: Have you checked arrow: http://crsmithdev.com/arrow/ it's pretty good a date time handling in many different formats

Comment: @user783836 : thanks, I will check

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `%z` directive for timezone when parsing the string with `datetime.strptime`:

```
from datetime import datetime

ist = '2015-07-24T19:23:49+0300'
dt_ist = datetime.strptime(ist, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')

print(dt_ist.year, dt_ist.month, dt_ist.day, dt_ist.tzinfo) 
# 2015 7 24 UTC+03:00
```

The directive is however not guaranteed to work on all machines

Comment: Thanks @Moses. But this is giving me error -     ValueError: 'z' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'

Comment: is this python version specific?